# ¿Saber cual polylinea esta mas cerca de una coordenada OpenLayer5?

Tags: openlayers

Tengo muy poco tiempo de usar openLayer ,estoy intentando obtener la ruta mas cercana a una coordenada
tengo 5 rutas actualmente que se crean con multiples coordenadas

```
var route1=[[5.072014331817627, -75.52483677864075],       [5.062379837036133, -75.52104949951172],       [5.062122344970703, -75.51032066345215],       [5.065984725952148, -75.51040649414062],       [5.062294006347656, -75.49791812896729]];
var route2=[[5.060148239135742,-75.52225112915039],[5.060920715332031,-75.49856185913086]];
```

las cuales me general una linea  para cada ruta

mi problema es que me dan una coordenada y debo obtener la distancia que tiene entre cada ruta ya sea entre el punto mas cercano que conforma esa ruta

Comment: Utilizar djastra seria una bueno opcion

Comment: lo utilice usando una extencion pero me da rutas erroneas